# Pinescript Fib retracement on first bar

Tags: plot, time, pine-script, fibonacci, pine-script-v4

I have been trying to find a way to automatically plot a fibonacci retracement on the opening bar of the the timeframe I'm on while extending it to right for the first 30 minutes. Have tried to modify several codes and have only managed to get it to set the fib on first bar but can't figure out how to get it to extend to the right and cut it off after 30 minutes. From all the research I've done here it seems the answer might be in using lines but after hours of frustrated attempts I am not understanding how to use this for fibs. This is the closest code I have to what I'm going for. Sorry if the code has unnecessary parts, I'm pretty new to coding! Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
//@version=4
study(title='opening fib', overlay=true)

timeframe = input('5', "Timeframe", input.resolution)
d_shift = -0
sessSpec = input("0930-1000", type=input.session)

is_newbar(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

newbar = is_newbar("1440", sessSpec)

var float s1 = na
var float s2 = na
var float s3 = na
var float s4 = na
if newbar
    s1 := low
    s2 := high
    s3 := open
    s4 := close

disp_f1 = input(true, title="236")
F1 = input(0.236, type=input.float)
disp_f2 = input(true, title="382")
F2 = input(0.382, type=input.float)
disp_f3 = input(true, title="50")
F3 = input(0.5, type=input.float)
disp_f4 = input(true, title="618")
F4 = input(0.618, type=input.float)
disp_f5 = input(true, title="-10")
F5 = input(-0.1, type=input.float)
disp_f6 = input(true, title="-15")
F6 = input(-0.15, type=input.float)
disp_f7 = input(true, title="-20")
F7 = input(-0.2, type=input.float)

fibrange = s2 - s1
if s4 >= s3
    F1 := s2 - F1 * abs(fibrange)
    F2 := s2 - F2 * abs(fibrange)
    F3 := s2 - F3 * abs(fibrange)
    F4 := s2 - F4 * abs(fibrange)
    F5 := s2 - F5 * abs(fibrange)
    F6 := s2 - F6 * abs(fibrange)
    F7 := s2 - F7 * abs(fibrange)
else
    F1 := s1 + F1 * abs(fibrange)
    F2 := s1 + F2 * abs(fibrange)
    F3 := s1 + F3 * abs(fibrange)
    F4 := s1 + F4 * abs(fibrange)
    F5 := s1 + F5 * abs(fibrange)
    F6 := s1 + F6 * abs(fibrange)
    F7 := s1 + F7 * abs(fibrange)
    

r_R1 = plot(title='-20', series=F7, offset=d_shift, color=color.red, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
r_R2 = plot(title='-15', series=F6, offset=d_shift, color=#1e90ff, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=1)
r_R3 = plot(title='-10', series=F5, offset=d_shift, color=color.green, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
r_s2 = plot(title='high', series=s2, offset=d_shift, color=color.green, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
r_R4 = plot(title='236', series=F1, offset=d_shift, color=#00bfff, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=1)
r_R5 = plot(title='382', series=F2, offset=d_shift, color=color.red, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
r_R6 = plot(title='50', series=F3, offset=d_shift, color=color.black, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2)
r_R7 = plot(title='618', series=F4, offset=d_shift, color=color.green, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=1)
r_s1 = plot(title='low', series=s1, offset=d_shift, color=color.red, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

youll first want to set a session using input.session() then calculate the high and low within that custom session. Then use lines to plot "x" number of bars past your session with the appropriate equations for their price - i.e. a price that is 150% would be = high+((high-low)/2)